# How to check if an object is of type Blob?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check if an object is of type Blob in JavaScript?

I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL does not implement
>   interface Blob.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727750/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-blob-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks. None of the similar search results came up today or I would have seen it was already answered. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using instanceof blob you can check.

```
var MyBlob = new Blob(['content'], {type : 'text/plain'});
console.log(MyBlob instanceof Blob) // true
```