# Inconsistent ArrayBuffer prototype in content script in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, content-script

In a Firefox browser extension I am writing, I wish to make a request from a content script in the context of a page (same cookies and authorizations, no CORS issues…). [This section of the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#xhr_and_fetch) mentions that I can use `content.fetch` and `content.XMLHttpRequest` to do that, though I can find no documentation on those or on `content` itself. When getting an `ArrayBuffer` from the response of `content.fetch`, I obtain a value which looks and acts like an `ArrayBuffer` but is not `instanceof ArrayBuffer`.

My assumption is that I am somehow dealing with an `ArrayBuffer` from the page context in the context of my content script, and that this value would have a different `ArrayBuffer` constructor. Is this something I can fix by messing with `wrappedJSObject` or something else? Or am I dealing with a browser bug?

More concretely, the following code behaves unexpectedly. The issue occurs even when this is the *only* code in the content script.

```
(async function () {
  const response = await content.fetch("./");
  console.log("response type", response instanceof Response);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  console.log("blob type", blob instanceof Blob);
  const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  console.log("array buffer", arrayBuffer);
  console.log("array buffer type", arrayBuffer instanceof ArrayBuffer);
})();
```

I expect this code to print this. (Last word is `true`.)

```
response type true
blob type true
array buffer ArrayBuffer { byteLength: … }
array buffer type true
```

In practice I get this. (Last word is `false`.)

```
response type true
blob type true
array buffer ArrayBuffer { byteLength: … }
array buffer type false
```

Comment: Instead of `instanceof`, use [`arrayBuffer.constructor.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55271454/10210841)

Comment: Thanks @Rojo, this is how I make my extension work despite this issue but the `instanceof` check happens in a dependency and I’d much rather have a fix in my code than maintain a patch for said dependency. Also I’d very much like to understand the issue.

Comment: Well I meant to say that see what happens when you try `arrayBuffer.constructor.name`. Just try it, and tell me the output

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. `arrayBuffer.constructor.name` gives the `ArrayBuffer` string.

Comment: Huh. Your best bet is to ask in the [JS chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript). Obviously by `arrayBuffer.constructor.name` your variable is an ArrayBuffer. If your code properly compiles with what you have, then I don't see why you should worry.